# parsing yaml in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, yaml, enumeration

If I have a yaml file like so:

```
-  name: James
   categories: "charming fun loving caring smart"
   description: "Blah blah"
-  name: Arthur
   categories: "loving funny smart"
   description: "Blah blah"
```

And I want to iterate over every single category in the yaml file also merging each tag in the categories entry and then eliminating the duplicates to make a complete list of all the categories, how can I do this?

I can map the categories fine with

```
data.products.map(&:categories)
```

but I also need to merge the individual words per category into the array as well.

```
data.products.map{|x| x.categories.split(" ")}.uniq!.each do |tag|
```

I'm a bit lost between maping all the categories and also marging the multple words per category.

Comment: It's not clear what you want as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think you just need a flatten in there :)

```
data.products.map { |x|
  x.categories.split
}.flatten.uniq
```

Comment: Ah perfect. I knew I was missing something small. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `map{...}.flatten` you can use [`flat_map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map)